# How to successfully send mail using a different domain than SMTP credentials?

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp, nodemailer, spf

I want to send out an email as myemail@domain2.com while being connected to domain1.com using domain1.com SMTP credentials. Both domain1.com and domain2.com have SPF records.

I did quite a bit of research and found that you should be able to achieve this by adding "a:domain1.com" into domain2.com's SPF record. I have done as such but I still cannot successfully send out an email.

I created a test code using node.js and nodemailer to test sending out the email.

```js
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

let transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'mail.domain1.com',
  port: 465,
  auth: {
    user: 'myemail@domain1.com',
    pass: 'password'
  }
});

const message = {
  from: 'myemail@domain2.com',
  to: 'test@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Testing 123',
  text: 'Testing One Two Three....'
};

transport.sendMail(message, function (err, info) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('err: ', err);
  } else {
    console.log('info: ', info);
  }
});
```

```
{ Error: Message failed: 550 Error458 block
at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\testsendmail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:784:19)
at SMTPConnection._actionSMTPStream (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\testsendmail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1661:34)
at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\testsendmail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1146:22)
at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\testsendmail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:942:20)
at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\testsendmail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:749:14)
at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData.chunk (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\testsendmail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:195:44)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10) 
code: 'EMESSAGE',
response: '550 Error458 block',
responseCode: 550,
command: 'DATA' }
```

Here are the SPF Records for the 2 domains:

domain1.com:

```
v=spf1 mx a ~all
```

domain2.com:

```
v=spf1 a a:domain1.com mx ?all
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to add a second domain as a mail source is to use the `include` mechanism:

```
v=spf1 a mx include:domain2.com ~all
```

I can't tell from what you've posted whether this is actually the cause of the error you're getting.

You might want to look into DKIM signing and DMARC as well.

While I'm here, there's no point in having a `?all` default mechanism; it's equivalent to not having an SPF record at all; use `~all` if you're using DMARC, `-all` otherwise (though be sure that **all** your mail sources are nailed down before doing that).

Comment: Do i add the include statement in the spf record of my domain1.com or domain2.com?

Comment: Of domain1.com. Check what’s in domain2’s record to be sure it is set up right too.

Comment: I found out that neither my domain1.com nor domain2.com has a DKIM, can not having a DKIM cause this issue?

Comment: DKIM is considerably more complicated to set up than SPF, and has no bearing on from address, but does also feed into DMARC. It all helps, so the best approach is to implement all of it, though it is quite a lot of work.